# Task Chaining when every task is dependent on certain events

Tags: c#, events, task

I have a requirement to connect to the `server` and collect data for processing.

Here is the `Connect` method

```
private readonly ServerComLibrary _vMyServer;// this is initialised in constructor 

public ConnectToServer(string servername)
{
  _vMyServer.connectToServerByName("ssl",servername);

}
```

`_vMyServer` has below events

- onConnectSucceeded - I will collect data and copy it to excel file
- onConnectFailed - just log the exception

Here is a connection success event

```
private void Handle_OnConnectSucceeded()
{
     //collect data and create excel 
}
```

Here is a Failed event

```
private void Handle_OnConnectFailed(int hr)
{
     //log exception
}
```

Everything works fine!

But, now my requirement is to connect to multiple servers one by one

```
List<Server> servers = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("servers") as List<Server>;
var datacollectionTasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var server in servers)
{
   var data = Task.Run(() => ConnectToServer(server.serveraddress));
   datacollectionTasks.Add(dataFix);
}
await Task.WhenAll(datacollectionTasks);
```

I want to start the `second task` only after `first task` of connecting to the server and creating excel generation compleats or connection fails.

How can I do it?  I may use `ContinueWith` but not sure how to confirm if events fired and job completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> my requirement is to connect to multiple servers one by one

Then I'm not sure why you're using `Task.WhenAll`.

> How can I do it? I may use ContinueWith but not sure how to confirm if events fired and job completed.

In order to chain tasks, you need a task to chain onto. Specifically, change the events into a `Task` by [using `TaskCompletionSource<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types#tasks-and-the-event-based-asynchronous-pattern-eap):

```
public static class ServerComLibraryExtensions
{
  public static Task ConnectAsync(this ServerComLibrary @this, string protocol, string host)
  {
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    Action onSucceeded = null;
    Action<int> onFailed = null;
    onSuccess = () =>
    {
      @this.OnConnectSucceeded -= onSucceeded;
      @this.OnConnectFailed -= onFailed;
      tcs.TrySetResult(null);
    };
    onFailed = hr =>
    {
      @this.OnConnectSucceeded -= onSucceeded;
      @this.OnConnectFailed -= onFailed;
      tcs.TrySetException(Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(hr));
    };
    @this.OnConnectSucceeded += onSucceeded;
    @this.OnConnectFailed += onFailed;
    @this.connectToServerByName(protocol, host);
    return tcs.Task;
  }
}
```

Now that the connect operation is represented as a `Task` instead of events, it can naturally be "chained" by using the `await` keyword:

```
List<Server> servers = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("servers") as List<Server>;
foreach (var server in servers)
{
  await _vMyServer.ConnectAsync("ssl", server.serveraddress);
  // collect data and create excel
}
```

Comment: so you mean, if OnConnectSucceeded event takes 5 mins to succeed, or timed out, the code will not pick the next item from foreach loop? then it's great.

Comment: Second question: How do I pass dependencies to extension classes? I want to log details using logger during connection success and failure events. This may not be possible while using extension methods or I believe we should try to avoid extension methods unless they only work on internal data.

Comment: @kudlatiger: 1) Yes. 2) That sounds like a completely different question; you'll get better results asking a separate question on SO rather than asking in a comment on an answer.

Comment: Thanks for input . I have created a question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57107015/how-do-i-pass-dependent-classes-to-extension-methods

Comment: COM reference and static classes might cause memory issue i believe